# Modify function which dynamically populates select elements to use arrays from db

Tags: php, arrays, html-select, populate

I'm trying to modify a function that I've been using to dynamically populate `<select>` element to use arrays from a database. The original function used hard-coded arrays to populate the elements, and pre-selected the option which matched the db value.

The revised function creates the  element, but it's only adding the first value from the db. How can I modify it so that it will loop through all the values that should be added to the `<select>` element?

*PHP Function and Query*

```
<?php
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection)) . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
try {  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM student");  
    $stmt->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
?>
```

*Populate Select Element*

```
<select name="fname">
    <?php
        echo printSelectOptions(array($row['fname'])); 
    ?>
</select>
```

**The Original Function & Code for Populating an Element**

```
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}

<select name="fname">
    <?php
        $options = array("John"=>"John", "Mary"=>"Mary", "Elizabeth"=>"Elizabeth");
        $selected = $row['fname'];
        echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected); 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: No need to change the function then. Just prepare the array list after the DB query. `->fetchAll` might help.

Comment: @mario - Thanks for letting me know about '->fetchAll'. Unfortunately this function needed a bit more than that, but thankfully Michael's answer got it working :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only fetched a single row via `fetch()`, only a single value is getting passed into your function `printSelectOptions()`.  Instead, get all rows via [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
 and modify your function to receive the full array, plus a *string* which is the column name (array key) you want to print from.

```
// All rows into $rows...
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Make the function accept the full 2D array, and 
// a string key which is the field name to list out:
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection, $fieldname) {
    // String to hold output
    $output = '';
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        // Rather than echo here, accumulate each option into the $output string
        // Use the $fieldname as a key to $value which is now an array...
        $output .= '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection)) . ' value="' . $key . '">' . htmlspecialchars($value[$fieldname], ENT_QUOTES) . '</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Then call the function as:

```
echo printSelectOptions($rows, $currentSelection, 'fname');
```

The way it is right now, the option's value attribute is populated by the array key, which would be numbered from zero.  That's similar to your original array version, but it might be more useful to specify another column name like `id` as the key column.

```
// This one also takes a $valuename to use in place of $key...
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection, $valuename, $fieldname) {
    // String to hold output
    $output = '';
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        // Rather than echo here, accumulate each option into the $output string
        // Use the $fieldname as a key to $value which is now an array...
        $output .= '<option ' . (($value[$valuename] == $currentSelection)) . ' value="' . $value[$valuename] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($value[$fieldname], ENT_QUOTES) . '</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

And would be called as:

```
    echo printSelectOptions($rows, $currentSelection, 'id', 'fname');
```

Comment: Those methods both worked perfectly :-D (I'm assuming you caught the problem with the one you'd posted earlier ;-) ) 2 questions - Is there a method in PHP similar to jQuery's (this) that could be used instead of 'fname' when the function is called? Also, out of curiosity, what would be the benefit of specifying another column name (like id) as the key column?

Comment: @ChayaCooper The reason for passing in `'fname'` is to make it generic so no matter what columns are in the `$rows` array, you can choose the column which gets output. So there isn't really a correlation to a jQuery `$(this)`, since in the PHP array context that `$(this)` is pointing to the `$value` in the foreach loop.

Comment: @ChayaCooper And specifying a column name just adds flexibility. Since the function has already been built to be generic and allow you to choose which column goes inside the `<option>` tag list, you might as well also allow to choose which column goes into `value=''`

Comment: You should probably also add a `htmlspecialchars()` around those, like `htmlspecialchars($value[$fieldname], ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: What you explained about the added flexibility will be super helpful for the next step in my project :-D At the moment I'm putting together a very long form and the <select> element names and db column names happen to be identical, so it would have been nice to save all that copying & pasting ;-) I'm assuming that there's no way to point to the name in the HTML parent element?

Comment: Out of curiosity, was I echoing something that I hadn't realized needed htmlspecialchars(), or are you suggesting it as something that's just good practice?

Comment: @ChayaCooper About pointing to the parent element - The PHP code really has no idea what's going on in the HTML, so no - but it could be done with JavaScript on the client side. That's more complicated and less reliable thoguh.

Comment: @ChayaCooper And about the htmlspecialchars() calls -- you should have those on any output that didn't come from something you hard-coded yourself.  If PHP outputs a value which has a `<` for example, htmlspecialchars() will encode it so it doesn't break the HTML.  And in a tag attribute, single or double quotes can break the HTML. So it's good practice to always use it, and essential to use it when you are outputting stuff from user input, as it protects your users against cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of that awesome and incredibly helpful information :-D

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to use this function to also add options dynamically to the array, or would I need to use a separate function for that?

Comment: @ChayaCooper Since the function is currently returning a string, the only way to make it modify the array would be to [pass the array by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and add to it in the function body.  I would not recommend doing that though, because then the function is suddenly doing two very different things (outputting a string, and modifying an input array), which gets really confusing.

Comment: I'm glad I asked you first :-D

Comment: Can I trouble you with one more question? Would you mind showing me how I can use this function when I want to create a 2 dimensional array without building a select element? I'm trying to modify the other scripts that I have on the page to use db values instead of hard-coded arrays, and I can't seem to get the syntax right to create an array for each column which would have the values of all the rows in it (and I've been reluctant to post the question because I'm afraid that's the kind of question that some members are likely to give me a hard time about :-( )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27138/discussion-between-michael-berkowski-and-chaya-cooper)

Comment: I'd love to, whenever you're free :-)